# Can I configure Eclipse to import java.util classes when similar named classes exist?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, dependencies, preferences

Problem statement: When using java.util classes like List or Set, Eclipse will not auto import the java.util classes because other classes with the same name exist (mainly from java.swt).

Goal: Auto import for List will choose java.util.List without asking back.

The "Favorits" preferences page is only helpful for static imports. I would like something like that for normal imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure a list of types to ignore in the Preferences in 'Java > Appearance > Type Filters'.

Types you filter out will not be shown in content assist, quick fix, or the Open Type dialog.

Example:
[image: Example type filters]